# Unloading Clojure vars from JVM thread-local space

Tags: java, memory-leaks, clojure

I'm writing a plugin for BaseX in Clojure, built via "lein uberjar" with the Clojure interpreter included. For the most part, this works well.

However -- when running via the BaseX HTTP instance, evaluation takes place inside Jetty's thread pool rather than having threads thrown away after a client disconnects.

As loading the plugin loads Clojure's classes through a custom classloader, and throwing away the (AOT-compiled) object instance which acts as the plugin's entry point does not discard the vars placed by Clojure in thread-local space, a classloader leak results with PermGen space being eventually exhausted by multiple instances of the Clojure interpreter.

How can this be resolved? I can make reasonable non-Clojure-specific changes to BaseX's module load/unload mechanism if necessary.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This idea might (or might not) work:

1. Don't make an uberjar, keep Clojure jars separate;
2. push Clojure jars up the classloader hierarchy by putting them into the main classpath of BaseX (edit the command line that starts BasexX server, something like `java -cp BaseX.jar;clojure.jar org.basex.BaseXServer`);
3. Package your plugin as a jar with just your code in it and rely on the Clojure classes already present in the main classpath.

Comment: That's actually what I'm doing as a workaround right now. I'm viewing it as a workaround, not a fix, because I think that including Clojure as part of the BaseX installation is simply the Wrong Thing -- having to modify the database installation whenever a plugin changes its dependency chain, for instance, is simply not clean.

Comment: Well, Clojure is, after all, a complete language execution environment, and not just any old jar dependency. To me this approach is more like making BaseX Clojure-enabled. All other dependencies could still be kept local to the plugin. It's not that often that you change the Clojure version you are using, could be even less often than upgrading BaseX itself.

Comment: I wish that were true -- I've hit a bug in Clojure 1.3.0 forcing me to move to the 1.4 beta series already. (If I had a second plugin written to target only, say, Clojure 1.1, this would be an exceptionally unfortunate situation). More to the point -- for *any* jar dependency not to be able to act as "just any old jar dependency" is, from an operational perspective, more than a little unfortunate. As such, I think it's reasonable to treat this as a thing to be fixed.

Comment: On the other hand, you wouldn't expect to be able to unload rt.jar, or run against two versions of Java at the same time. I agree that if you had a plugin targeted only for Java 1.3, it would be a very unfortunate situation. It's a grey area, I'd say...