# Overheads involved in OSGI

Tags: osgi, overhead

OSGI is a buzzword today. It has many advantages like loose coupling, reusability. But i want to know whether there are any overheads involved with OSGI as i have to use in my project. Does it effect speed or any other kind of overhead. Please help

Thanks

Answer (score 4):

There is no real overhead. OSGi was designed to work in very memory-constrained environments, and it can actually make execution speed better because of the smaller class space to search for each load request.

It is always possible for a naïve developer to screw up performance by doing silly things, but that is true of any environment.

Comment: I have trouble with the assertion that the only errors which can be made are "naïve" and "silly". See the still-unanswered http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10093087/unloading-clojure-vars-from-jvm-thread-local-space for an example, and note that one doesn't need to make this kind of error yourself -- if one of your libraries does it for you, that's enough to leak. (To be clear -- OSGi is quite certainly a Good Thing, but telling people that there are no gotchas involved is setting folks up for trouble).

Comment: Your link leads to a question about Clojure, I don't see the relevance. And most of the problems you complain about (here in your own answer) relate to dynamic reloading. Well nobody will force you to dynamically reload; and in standard Java you basically can't do this anyway so it's not relevant the comparison.

Comment: A question about unloading the Clojure runtime. Can't unload it, but getting ready to swap out versions of a component that uses it? You just got yourself a classloader leak.

Comment: Indeed, nobody is forcing you to do dynamic reloading. Likewise, nobody is forcing you to take advantage of OSGi's ability to solve transitive dependency conflicts -- but avoiding those problems is a good chunk of the point of using it, but making use of that capability means you have multiple instances of the same class loaded, so you're using more PermGen space (even with no reloading in use).

Comment: Actually it's very rare to load multiple copies of the same class in OSGi except when dynamically updating.

Comment: If that's true, then using OSGi to avoid transitive dependency conflicts is also very rare. (Mind you, these "multiple copies" can be of different versions -- perhaps misleading wording, but I wasn't the first person to use the exact phrase "multiple copies" in this thread).

Answer (score 2):

In a typical OSGi environment you will have the bundle classloader and OSGi services where you could suspect they affect performance. The bundle classloader simply sees a smaller space of classes so it should not be slower than a normal classloader. In some cases it could be even faster like Neil wrote. The OSGi services also should not affect performance. Basically they are just a way to look up Impl classes for an interface. So once you have the Impl resolved it is just a method call with no overhead. There is no serialization and no proxies involved.

Answer (score 2):

The largest negative production impact of using OSGi is the increase in PermGen space required due to having multiple versions of classes loaded with different classloaders. Unless using JRockit (where allocated from the OS as-needed), maximum PermGen size is fixed at JVM startup, and can be hard to clear if one has classloader leaks (which are easy to collect), making it potentially a somewhat limited resource.

There is not substantial performance impact. There may be some cognitive load in knowing what to expect in corner cases -- for instance, instances of the "same class" loaded through different classloaders will result in them having different types (`instanceof` returning false in cases where comparing `obj.getClass().getName()` return true) -- but performance will not be impacted.

Comment: I think in practice you can avoid having classes loaded in several classloaders most of the time. If you do not embed foreign classes and instead use Import-Package like you should in most cases then they should only be loaded once.

Comment: @ChristianSchneider If you're using Import-Package the way you're supposed to -- with versions specified -- you can end up needing multiple versions simply because multiple versions need to be loaded to satisfy these dependencies. More to the point -- consider plugin upgrade scenarios. Leave something in a thread pool's thread-local space? Old version's classloader can't be unloaded, a new version of the thread gets a new classloader, and you've got a leak.

Comment: Definately possible but it only happens when you have an error in the code. We might need some better tools to find such things though. Btw. the same can probably happen in tomcat.

Comment: @ChristianSchneider Tomcat has quite a bit of code intended to dig through thread-local space in thread pool members and try to eliminate instances attached to classes associated with unloaded applications. You're right that getting similar tools for Felix & co. would be a very nice thing.

Comment: @Duffy how would you solve the problem of needing multiple versions of the same class without increasing permgen space?

Comment: @PeterKriens One can't solve that problem without increasing permgen usage. Just because something is an overhead doesn't mean it's avoidable, fixable, or not well worth the tradeoff... but it's silly, perhaps even dishonest, to sweep things under the carpet and not tell people evaluating a solution that tradeoffs do exist, especially when they ask that question explicitly. Newcomers may not even know that there _exists_ such a thing as PermGen space.

Comment: So there is no price to pay for OSGi as is, there is a price to pay if you want multiple versions of the same class in the a vm. Though OSGi supports this, there is no requirement to do this, the purpose of OSGi is that it is a component programming model making software more reusable and easier to maintain. It has huge advantages over classic Java and for that you do not perse have to have multiple versions.

Comment: @PeterKriens Just so -- there's unavoidable overhead inherent in the capabilities that OSGi gives you, though it can be avoided if one is careful not to exercise all of those capabilities. Why would you not tell someone this when they ask the question directly?